# Error 500 on adding repo from GitHub to developer-story

Tags: bug, developer-story, github

I recently created a repo ("starter-kits") on GitHub. I was trying to add it to developer-story, a few times, and failed to add it. I get error 500 each time (the page itself get stucked). Image attached. What can I do?
[image]